# How do I use Repository pattern and Interactor pattern in a Model View Presenter pattern?

Tags: java, android, repository-pattern, mvp, interactors

I am developing an application with the help of Model View Presenter pattern.

I make use of Retrofit and so I have a ApiClient and ApiInterface with endpoints. I implement the interface in a RemoteDataSource class which I call in the Repository class.

My questions is - how do I make use of an Interactor class to make the repository communicate with the Presenter?

Here is my code until now:

**ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("?")
Call<ArrayList<Movie>> getMoviesByTitle(@Query("t") String title,@Query("apiKey") String apiKey);

}
```

**RemoteDataSource class**

```
private static MovieRemoteDataSource instance;
private final ApiInterface service;

public MovieRemoteDataSource(ApiInterface movieApi) {
    service = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static MovieRemoteDataSource getInstance(ApiInterface movieApi) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MovieRemoteDataSource(movieApi);
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void getMovies(String title, String apiKey, final LoadMovieCallBack callback) {
    service.getMoviesByTitle(title,apiKey).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Movie>> call, Response<ArrayList<Movie>> response) {
            ArrayList<Movie> movies = response.body();// != null ? //response.body().getTitle() : null;
            if (movies != null && !movies.isEmpty()) {
                callback.onMoviesLoaded(movies);
            } else {
                callback.onDataNotAvailable();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Movie>> call, Throwable t) {
            callback.onError();
        }
    });
}
```

**DataSource interface with a callback**

```
public interface MovieDataSource {
    interface LoadMovieCallBack{
        void onMoviesLoaded(ArrayList<Movie> movies);
        void onDataNotAvailable();
        void onError();

    }

    void getMovies(String title, String apiKey,LoadMovieCallBack callback);

}
```

**Repository**

```
 private MovieRemoteDataSource movieRemoteDataSource;


public MoviesRepository() {//ApiInterface movieApi) {
    //this.service = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static MoviesRepository getInstance(ApiInterface service) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MoviesRepository();
    }
    return instance;
}





  public void getMovies(String title, String apiKey ) {
        movieRemoteDataSource.getMovies(title,apiKey,this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MoviesRepository` you should declare a function with `Callback`. Your `Presenter` 
 should implement `MovieDataSource.LoadMovieCallBack` and pass it when you call `MoviesRepository`

```
  public void getMovies(String title, String apiKey,MovieDataSource.LoadMovieCallBack callback) {
        movieRemoteDataSource.getMovies(title,apiKey,callback);
  }
```

[Here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/deprecated-todo-mvp-contentproviders/todoapp) is Google `MVP` already done for todo app sample, you can refer it. But now it deprecated because Google recommends `MVVM`

Comment: Well, yes but I want to make use of Interactor(Use case). How would that work?